# Fallout 4 - Where are the quests

Tags: fallout-4

I'm stuck in Fallout 4 for PSX4. I have done almost all quests that I found (both main and side ones). I finished the main quest. Now I am lost completely. I do not have any more quests. BoS Maxon says there are quests for me, but I cant find them at all.

I do have Minutemen repeating quests, but other then that nothing is happening. I can wonder around, find quests that I missed, but there is no main line story... nothing. What I am missing?

I don't prefer wondering around and leveling, I would like something to do.

Comment: You... uh.. you finished the game, and now you're wondering where the main story is? It's over. You finished it.

Comment: I feel sorry for finishing it :)

Comment: Do what I did - start another playthrough.   Or do what other people do, and make it a point to discover every location on the map.   Or buy the DLC with far harbor.  That's got a whole new set of quests.

Comment: Do we include the game name in the question titles here, in addition to tags? All those SE sites with different rules - so confusing ;)

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you finished the main story line. What Maxson refers to is the quests given by paladin Danse's team.
You could try to add mods to your game to track down the quests that you are missing or change the gameplay.

If you finished all the quests, you may want to fix some objectives for yourself like chasing all the unique monsters and deathclaws, gathering power armors, exploring vaults, building huge settlements or trying new perks.

Last but not least, you should consider exploring the sea bottom and the irradiated area in the south.

If this is not enough, all that's left to do is to buy a DLC

Comment: Sea bottom? Could you provide location? :)

Comment: I found a map on [this website](https://www.google.fr/amp/s/gamerant.com/fallout-4-underwater-map/amp/) but beware of spoilers. Honestly there isn't much to do underwater and the visibility is close to none but there is a nice easter egg and a weapon to get.

Comment: You can also reroll a new character and do one of the other main quest paths.  Fallout 4 is ostensibly an RPG.